# Android ViewPager with LinearLayout at the button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have an Activity, that uses a ViewPager to page through two ListFragments -- this works great.

I am attemtpting to add some type of layout at the bottom that has an EditText, a Button, and a TextView. I want this to be fixed at the bottom of the screen, not scroll with the ListFragment.

My view looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But because I use this in my onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
}
```

This view isn't even being read. The problem is I'm not sure how to use a ViewPager AND specify a layout, allowing me to add such a layout at the bottom.. can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just use the setConentView as normal, and reference the ViewPager by id.. not sure why I had a problem with this..?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.application);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mTabsAdapter = new OURSVPTabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you setting your content view to `mViewPager`, which isn't using the layout.

Rather than create new ViewPager object, use the layout xml you've crated. If it's called `activity_main.xml` set it via `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Maybe something like this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<Button... your button here />
<TextView ... your text here />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Maybe post the activity code you are using to attach the adapter to the pager? also what's not working?

Comment: What you are suggesting is right, but without setting the viewpager the viewpager didnt work, I had to set it in the tabsadapter.. your answer is half way there

Comment: @scottyab I am trying the same layout but now the viewpager doesn't work , where should I attach the adapter then ?